# dplyr- conditional and multiple filters grouped-by

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to filter based in more than conditions  in a generalizable way with a dplyr feel. My objective is is to filter to get the just the first month when a group got the goal of 40000. Given this data.

```
group month    output cumulouput  indi
(fctr) (int)     (dbl)      (dbl) (dbl)
  A     1  9735.370    9735.37     0
  A     2 10468.063   20203.43     0
  A     3 11494.736   31698.17     0
  B     1 10186.465   10186.46     0
  B     2  9771.083   19957.55     0
  B     3  9871.636   29829.18     0
  B     4  9877.264   39706.45     0
  B     5  9009.198   48715.65     1
  B     6  9874.526   58590.17     1
  C     1 10613.868   10613.87     0
  C     2 10503.673   21117.54     0
  C     3 10397.098   31514.64     0
  C     4  9709.228   41223.87     1
  C     5  9861.669   51085.54     1
  C     6  9137.551   60223.09     1
```

For each group is to get the minimum month when group got the goal and the maximum month when group didn't reach the  goal. (???)

This is the the result of the filter:

```
group   month    output cumulouput  indi
(fctr) (int)     (dbl)      (dbl) (dbl)
  A     3 11494.736   31698.17     0
  B     5  9994.509  51800.365     1
  C     4  9709.228   41223.87     1
```

For the data:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=6),  month = rep(1:6,3))     %>% 
arrange(group,month) %>% 
mutate(output = rnorm(n=18,mean = 10000, sd = 722))%>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(cumulouput=cumsum(output))%>% 
filter(!(group=="A"&month>=4)) %>% 
mutate( indi= ifelse(cumulouput>40000,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the desired output, although I feel it can be shortened up a bit.

```
library(dplyr)
  df1 <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=6),  month = rep(1:6,3))     %>% 
  arrange(group,month) %>% 
  mutate(output = rnorm(n=18,mean = 10000, sd = 722))%>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cumulouput=cumsum(output))%>% 
  filter(!(group=="A"&month>=4)) %>% 
  mutate( indi= ifelse(cumulouput>40000,1,0))

one <- df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  .[.$cumulouput > 40000,] %>% 
  filter(row_number(cumulouput) == 1)

two <- df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  .[.$indi == 0,]

three <- rbind(one,two) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(cumulouput == max(cumulouput))%>%
  arrange(group)

head(three)
```

Comment: This doesn't show the max month if goal not reached

Answer (score -1):

The logic here goes as follows, for each `group` for each row it checks if `indi==1` if `TRUE` it returns the `min` month with goal satisfied if `FALSE` it returns the `max` month with goal not satisfied.
Then `filter` `month`s who matches the ones we just added and `filter` for `max(indi)` to remove previous months of a `group`.
Finally remove the temp column `m`

```
df1 %>% group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(m=if_else(indi==1, min(.[.$indi==1,'month']), max(.[.$indi==0,'month']))) %>% 
    filter(month==m, indi==max(indi)) %>%
    select(-m)
```

Comment: Hello Mabdrabo, the logic is good but I tried and didn't show the desired ouput. Because de temp m colum it shows just 4. for every row.